# MySQL cursor exits prematurely

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a SP cursor which works fine with all sets of data , except one. This SP has nested cursors in it. 
The cursor is like this:

```
...
BLOCK1: begin
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select date, value1, value2 from excel.tc where date >= first_mov and id_fk = idz order by date DESC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN cur1;

read_loop_1: LOOP

    FETCH cur1 into datez, value1z, value2z;  

    IF done THEN
        'exit loop
...lots of code

END LOOP;
end BLOCK1;
```

My nested cursors follow the same model, opening blocks and declaring cursors and handlers. The SP works except with a specific set of data; the cursor won't go through all rows, even though all values from CURSOR FOR SELECT are correct (I've debugged it). And this data doesn't have anything different, except rows are not physically ordered by **date**.

Is there anything that would cause this issue? I'm using MySQL 5.0.26.

**EDIT: Some data to illustrate:

Using this set of data **does not** work, cursor stops at third row (when ordered by date, desc):

```
date        value1     value2    id_fk     id
2006-02-17  0.920000   1.000000  12        25
2006-12-22  0.912000   1.000000  12        26
2007-04-24  0.818000   1.000000  12        27
2004-07-30  0.013650   1.000000  12        820
2004-10-30  0.012280   1.000000  12        821
2004-12-31  0.008960   1.000000  12        822
2005-04-16  0.006350   1.000000  12        823
2005-12-23  0.000000   -20.00000 12        824
2005-12-23  0.630000   1.000000  12        825
2003-12-31  0.020480   1.000000  12        826
2004-04-24  0.000850   1.000000  12        827
```

Comment: Do you possibly run into a timeout or other configured server limits?

Comment: @Michel Feldheim no, it just exits the loop and continues.

Comment: And procedure continues to run?

Comment: @Michel Feldheim Yes it does. Well I just checked with a debug table and it seems my debugging tool was not accurate, `done` goes to 1 as expected. So the issue is the cursor itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I had a `select into var...` which returned `null`, and was considered a condition for `NOT FOUND` for the handler.  This is well documented but I missed it somehow.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same problem and it took me a day to dismantle my stored procedure and find why the cursor exited prematurely before I found your solution. Thanks!